# iptables chain to forward between two identical networks

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

I have two identical networks and I am looking to forward traffic between two computers which are configured as a TCP server and a TCP client respectively.  Using a computer which is connected to both networks I am hoping to use iptables to forward this data.  I am hoping to initiate the TCP connection from the client to the forwarder and have it then establish the connection with the server.

e.g. TCP Client (1.1.1.155) establishes a connection with the Forwarder (1.1.1.55), and it intern forwards the request to the server (1.1.1.155) to complete the connection.   See diagram below.

[image: Basic Network Diagram]

I've enabled ipv4 forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I've cleared out my iptables configuration

```
iptables -F
```

The iptables configuration I've been trying is:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth2 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.155
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Can you pls mention what is failing here? Any thing particular

Comment: do you have a question of some kind?

Comment: Have you compared the effort to get this right, and the fragility of that solution, to the effort it would take to just change one of the networks from `1.1.1.*/24` to, say, `1.1.2.*/24`? (assuming you actually do use a private network range; identical public IP addresses are not permitted, for exactly the reason you encounter here that most things will stop working)

Comment: While it's possible to configure routing for this, conntrack (nat) can't be configured to distinguish addresses coming from lanA and lanB. This will make most of the connections work, but a new connection using an inverted pair of ports of an already existing connection would fail (and can be seen only by checking invalid state in mangle/PREROUTING because tcp state doesn't match).

Answer (score 0):

This current design might not work for you. Your current issue reminds me of VPN where local subnet is identical to remote subnet. Back to your design, forwarder will be a VPN server. To make this work:

```
LAN-A subnet will remain unchanged
LAN-B subnet will remain unchanged
eth1 and eth2 on forwarder must belong to two unique subnets, without conflicting with each other or with LAN-A and LAN-B.
```

Once you meet these conditions, then you must use NAT in your firewall rules. Keep in mind that forwarder will act as a gateway. For a gateway to work, it must have at least two network interfaces on different subnets, as suggested earlier.